# Puppet Asp.net web.config

Tags: web-config, puppet

We are looking for using hierra data configuration for Application configuration management.  Asp.net uses Web.config and App.config files which have the configuration values as key , value pairs 
Example:

```
<appSettings>
<add key="key1" value="Web"/>
<add key="key2" value="16.2"/>
</appSettings>
```

Currently we are using **EPP templates with place holders** for the values and generate the file on the fly.

```
<add key="key1" value="<%= $class_name::value1%>"/>
```

Just wanted to check whats the **best practice for managing configuration files like web.config, app.config using Puppet**. Suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Using templates to generate dynamic content for these seems good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Templates

The recommendation is nearly always templates when you can control the entire file. There is [fairly comprehensive documentation on templating](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_template.html).

- Use [EPP](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_template_epp.html) for Puppet 4.x+.
- Use [ERB](https://docs.puppet.com/puppet/latest/lang_template_erb.html) for Puppet 3.x+.

#### XML Fragments

If you cannot or do not want to control the whole file, another alternative is [xml_fragment available on the forge](https://forge.puppet.com/ianoberst/xml_fragment) (https://forge.puppet.com/ianoberst/xml_fragment).

You can see that it's a bit more verbose than templating, but has granularity for purging and ensuring elements for a file.

```
xml_fragment { "appsetting key1":
  path        => "C:/sites/site/web.config",
  ensure      => 'present',
  xpath       => "/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='key1']",
  content     => {
    attributes {
      "value" => "web"
    }
  }
}

xml_fragment { "appsetting key2":
  path        => "C:/sites/site/web.config",
  ensure      => 'present',
  xpath       => "/configuration/appSettings/add[@key='key2']",
  content     => {
    attributes {
      "value" => "16.2"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the input, We managed to write a powershell script to manage the XML file. We get the hashtable input form hiera for values and pass it to the scripts. Created a mapper docs with xpath and hiera key mapping. Now We made it common library to use in all of our puppet modules.